# How do display all the team names with their ids from a json file like this with python

Tags: python, json

https://www.goalserve.com/getfeed/2633a3fcbb2b4558740708d89fcf1b20/football/nfl-standings

i watched a couple videos about extracting json objects with python, but i havnt been able to find any with objects within objects.

```
import pandas as pd
import random 
import numpy as np
import requests
import json
 
#%%
response = requests.get("https://www.goalserve.com/getfeed/2633a3fcbb2b4558740708d89fcf1b20/football/nfl-standings?json=1")
output = response.json()
 
# Extract specific node content.
data = output['standings']['category']['league']
# print(output['standings']['category']['league'])
 

#print(type(data))

#for team in range(len(data)):
 #   print(team['division'])


# Dump data as string
data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
print(data)


for team in data['division']['team']:
   print(team)
```

i get this error "string indices must be integers". How can i access the attributes for each team record?

Comment: update: print(type(output))
# Extract specific node content.
data = output['standings']['category']['league']
# print(output['standings']['category']['league'])
 
print(type(data))
#print(type(data))

print(data[0]['division'][0]['team'][0]['name']), this is displaying the team name

Answer (score 0):

Hi According to your code I can see one flaw that is been there is no validation.

make these two validations after that manipulate the request

1. `if response.status_code==200`
2. `if response and response.text`

after validating you can pass the response for the data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here. First is that this line:

```py
data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
```

converts the data structure in the `data` variable back to a string so you can't treat it like a dictionary.

The second problem is that the data structure here is a mix of dictionaries and lists, so you need to treat `data` which is the list of leagues as a list, not a dictionary. The same goes for `league['division']` and `division['team']`.

Here's a version that prints the team names:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://www.goalserve.com/getfeed/2633a3fcbb2b4558740708d89fcf1b20/football/nfl-standings?json=1")
output = response.json()

data = output['standings']['category']['league']

for league in data:
  for division in league['division']:
    for team in division['team']:
      print(team['name'])
```